# How do I type em dash — like that — on windows phone?

Tags: 8.0, keyboard

I've been trying to find it for half a year, but found only the en dash, same as minus sign. How can we type the long dash on WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get unicode-ASCII converters from App Store. Use following unicode to convert to ur em hash. (I can't suggest you one because it's violation of policy)

```
figure dash     ‒   \u2012
en dash         –   \u2013
em dash         —   \u2014
horizontal bar  ―   \u2015
swung dash      ⁓   \u2053
```